# How to rotate an image by a random amount using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random, numbers

I have a gallery of 20 images on my web page that I would like to rotate by a random amount (-5 to 5 degrees) upon hover over each image. If possible, I'd like to use just CSS. If not, I would be open to using JavaScript or jQuery.

My CSS is as follows:

```
.photo:hover {
    z-index:1;
    transform:rotate(6deg) scale(1.25);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(6deg) scale(1.25);
    -moz-transform:rotate(6deg) scale(1.25);
    -ms-transform:rotate(6deg) scale(1.25);
}
```

6deg should be a random number, so every time the user hovers over an image, it rotates by a random amount between -5 and 5. Can I call a JavaScript function from within the CSS, or even a JavaScript variable? That would be better than creating 20 different CSS ids.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot include Javascript in CSS. Just use jQuery to change the degree on hover.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You won't need separate CSS IDs, but you could use some jQuery on the class. `.each()` is used instead of `.css()` directly here because otherwise the random angle would be generated once and used for all of the images. To rotate individally on hover:

```
$('.photo').hover(function() {
    var a = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + a + 'deg) scale(1.25)');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'none');
});
```

If you want to smoothly animate these transformations, you can simply add a `transform` CSS property to the class:

```
.photo {
    transition: transform 0.25s linear;
}
```

Demonstration: http://jsbin.com/iqoreg/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I love that doing it this way even gives you a different rotation degree when hovering on and off the same element.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I've found this via Google in 2022 and there is a pseudo random way to achieve a similar effect with pure CSS.

It does take some tweaking the rotations and order of positive and negative values to match your design width, or it will generate a very visible repeating pattern.

Try it out and play with the values until you find something that matches your design.

```css
/* setup */
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #E54575;
}
/* maaagic */
div { transform:rotate(5deg); }
div:nth-child(2n) { transform:rotate(-4deg); }
div:nth-child(3n) { transform:rotate(2deg); }
div:nth-child(4n) { transform:rotate(-5deg); }
div:nth-child(5n) { transform:rotate(-6deg); }
div:nth-child(6n) { transform:rotate(6deg); }
/* ... you can add or remove more rotations here... */
```

```html
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```