# Randomly rotating html element

Tags: javascript, random, rotation, position

I was looking to make a bunch of list items randomly rotated (and *absolutely* placed) on the screen and found out here that that can only be achieved with javascript, instead of css3 as my first attempts were.

I found a beautiful solution in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504750/how-to-rotate-an-image-by-a-random-amount-using-css) but it makes the rotation only when hovering. Since I'm no javascript expert, I wasn't able to do that on load, instead of hover.

After that I would find a way to do randomly input the *top* and *left* values, but if you already have that solution, I would love to hear it.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the referenced *beautiful solution*, you can just reuse that, but call it when the page is loaded, like this:

```
// this will be called onload
jQuery(function($) {
    // changed .hover to .each
    $('.photo').each(function() {
        var a = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + a + 'deg)');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shanon! This seems right to me, but I couldn't manage to make it do it. [Here's a codepen with my attempt](http://codepen.io/GuiHarrison/pen/ycwdf)

Comment: I've updated your codepen and tweaked the JS.  It's working for me in Chrome, now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fIilF

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){         
        $(elSelector).each(function(){
            var a = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + a + 'deg) scale(1.25)');
        });
});
```

Comment: why on earth the setInterval?

Comment: I thought he wants to animate it continuously. Edited now.