# Trying to tilt multiple divs to different, random angles

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, random, tilt

I'm trying to achieve the opposite of what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504750/how-to-rotate-an-image-by-a-random-amount-using-css).

I have a series of divs in a wordpress page, which I would like to appear on the page as each randomly tilted to a different slight degree.

They should also be straightened up as the user hovers on them.

Here's what I have:

```
    (function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var a = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        $('.format-aside').each(function( index ) { 
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + a + 'deg)');})
        });
})(jQuery);
```

at first, I skipped the `.each` part, but this resulted in all the divs being tilted the same way. However even with the `.each` they still end up tilted the same way.

As to the hover effect, I have set it in the CSS page:

```
.format-aside:hover{-ms-transform: rotate(0deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
transform: rotate(0deg);}
```

and it worked when all of this was done in CSS (but of course then all divs tilted the same way). Now it doesn't work anymore so I figure I should add the hover effect in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they're all tilted the same amount is because you calculate the degree before iterating over the elements. Instead, you should calculate one angle per element:

```
(function($) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.format-aside').each(function( index ) { 
        // rotation degree between -5 and 5
        var a = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + a + 'deg)');})
    });
})(jQuery);
```

As for the hover effect try adding the `!important` option to them:

```
.format-aside:hover {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
}
```

The reason for your CSS not working is because jQuery applies the rules on the elements as in-line styles. These are higher priority than any CSS selectors. Using the `!important` rule you can override that.

Comment: Thank you Hubert, you are correct, now it works as expected. That was lazy of me actually.